# lottie-animated svg very pixelated/blurry in Safari but not Chrome/FF

Tags: safari, scaling, svg-animate, lottie, blurry

macOS Mojave
After Effects 17.0.2 (CC 2020)
newest Versions of Chrome/FF/Safari and Lottie/Bodymovin

When scaling a svg-animation in Safari (transform: scale(>1)), it will be rendered extremely pixelated/blurred. In Chrome and Firefox it renders without problems. Is this a known issue and if so, is there a known workaround?

You can find the animation here:
http://kb.zeitweisen.com/Index.html

Comment: I ended up scaling the animation with width/height and then used "transform: translate()" to push it into place. Not the most elegant way but at least it gives me the same result.

Answer (score 6):

I hava the same problem . svg is blurry in Safari .

svg element have

```
transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
```

I cover this style

```
transform: unset !important;
```

It works for me

Comment: you saved my day, thanks a lot for the fix

Comment: This worked for me as well, thanks! Mine was blurry in Chrome

Comment: Perfect. You saved me a lot of time!

Comment: for me, this also fixed blurry lottie svg in chrome